# How to determine the parent of child menu item in ToolStripMenu?

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripmenu

I am a hobby programmer. In my C# 2010 Express + SQL Server 2008 desktop application I am trying to add code to click event of childitem. I want to determine the parent (menuitem) of this child menu item. How can I find it?

Comment: You mean you want to determine that which menu has pressed to load this current form? or you want to get the parent menu item of the clicked menu strip item?

Comment: yes. I have menu called operation. in that submenus are Add, edit, delete, in the every submenu there is same database names to select. I want to know from which submenu I have selected the database.

Comment: Have you tried that solution?

Comment: yes. Getting error in second line of code-- Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
private void mnuDatabase1_Click(object sender, ...)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem MyMenuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    ToolStripMenuItem parent = (ToolStripMenuItem)MyMenuItem.OwnerItem;
    if (parent.Name == "mnuAdd")
        //Add Menu
    else if (parent.Name == "mnuEdit")
        //Edit Menu
    else if (parent.Name == "mnuDelete")
        //Delete Menu
}
```

Comment: Getting error  in second line of code-- Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Sorry i have forgot to cast the OwnerItem to `ToolStripMenuItem` class object.

Comment: Isn't that amazing. The error message *suggested the actual fix*. Why didn't you try that, Muni?

Comment: sorry but i didn't get meaning of that. I tried declaring , ToolStripMenuItem OwnerItem = new ToolStripMenuItem. it didn't solve the error.

Comment: Cody Grey, Thanks, I went through old post. It solves my purpose partially. I will try myself further & get back if required.